# asynchronously load a group of modules

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In Vue.js (2.X) I can make a component load asynchronously - which means the code for that component will be stored in a separate bundle - by changing the corresponding route's definition from

```js
// routes.js

import Messages from '@/views/messages'

export default [
  {
    path: '/messages',
    name: 'messages',
    component: Messages
  }
]
```

to

```js
// routes.js

export default [
  {
    path: '/messages',
    name: 'messages',
    component: () => import('@/views/messages')
  }
]
```

Is there a way that I can bundle 2 (or more) route components together, such that the code for them is stored in the same bundle and loaded (asynchronously) simultaneously?

The reason I want to do this is because the components in this group are only accessible to a user with a certain role, so either all of them are accessible to a user, or none of them are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html#grouping-components-in-the-same-chunk).

---

### @vue/cli

If you develop using `@vue/cli`, you're using webpack under the hood and you need to tell webpack how to group its chunks, using comments inside `import()`:

```js
const Foo = () =>
  import(/* webpackChunkName: "foo-bar" */ './Foo.vue')
const Bar = () =>
  import(/* webpackChunkName: "foo-bar" */ './Bar.vue')
const Baz = () =>
  import(/* webpackChunkName: "baz" */ './Baz.vue')
```

---

### vite

In you develop using `vite`, you're using rollup under the hood and you need to tell rollup how to group chunks, in `vite.config.js`:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      // https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputmanualchunks
      output: {
        manualChunks: {
          'foo-bar': [
            './src/Foo',
            './src/Bar',
          ],
          baz: [
             './src/Baz'
          ]
        },
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As it happens, I'm using Vite. Would you be able to clarify what exactly the values './src/Foo', './src/Bar', './src/Baz' refer to? Maybe it would be more obvious if you showed the routes as well for the Vite app

Comment: They refer to your `.vue` files. In your case, they'd point to `@/views/SomeComponent`. I'm not entirely sure the `@` alias works inside `vite.config.js` without some additional setup (I don't think it does), so you might want to use `'./src/views/SomeComponent'`. Inside your routes, you're still supposed to use `component: () => import('@/views/SomeComponent')`. When you build, rollup will manage the manual chunks as specified in `rollupOptions` of `vite.config.js`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. So I don't need the /* webpackChunkName */ comments in the case of Vite, just make sure the components are asynchronously imported?

Comment: The async importing doesn't change. It's `() => import()` in both cases. But you need to inform the bundler on how to bundle/group the chunks. webpack needs comments in `import()`, rollup needs `vite.config.js > rollupOptions.output.manualChunks` config.